# Phasors: why is my book using sines?

Tags: phasor

When I learned phasors I learned we passed from sinusoidal to phasor this way:

$$\sqrt{2} V\cos(\omega t+\phi) \rightarrow \sqrt{2} Ve^{j\phi}$$

However I'm now studying for a book that does this:

$$\sqrt{2} V\sin(\omega t+\phi) \rightarrow Ve^{j\phi}$$

Is this some kind of notation that I am not familiar with? Can I accept this as correct? I«m facing this notation studying three-phase systems, while the first notation was used in the context of circuit analysis.

Thank you!

Comment: What formula do your two sources give for calculating the power delivered by a (phasor) voltage applied to a load?

Comment: Is there a mathematical relationship between sines and cosines?

Comment: Most modern textbooks I saw use a cosine-phasor. A sine-phasor is also present, but not that popular. It is actually just about selecting a Real axis on the phasor space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also saw the first definition in my education:

$$v(t) = \mathcal{R}\left\{\underline{V}\cdot e^{j\omega t}\right\} = \mathcal{R}\left\{(V\cdot e^{j\phi})\cdot e^{j\omega t}\right\} = V\cdot\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$

But as long as you are consistent with your formulation, both will lead to the same results when analyzing problems. The phasor amplitude will now represent the RMS value of the sinusoidal signal, and the phase will be relative to a sine wave (90 degrees shifted compared to the cosine).

[EDIT] If you're also interested in *how* exactly they're linked:

Both definitions are still strongly linked. Using the second definition is basically identical to

$$\begin{align}
v(t) &= \mathcal{I}\left\{\underline{V}'\cdot \sqrt{2} e^{j\omega t}\right\}\\
&= \mathcal{I}\left\{(V'\cdot e^{j\phi'})\cdot \sqrt{2} e^{j\omega t}\right\}\\ &=\sqrt{2}V'\cdot \sin(\omega t + \phi')\\
&= (\sqrt{2}V')\cdot \cos\left(\omega t + \left(\phi' - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

And you can find that

$$\begin{align}
V &= \sqrt{2}V'\\
\phi &= \phi' - \frac{\pi}{2}\\
\underline{V} &= Ve^{j\phi} = (\sqrt{2}V')e^{j(\phi'-\frac{\pi}{2})} = -j\sqrt{2}\cdot \underline{V'}
\end{align}$$

Comment: What is being proved here? This doesn't proof the second equation PO posted.

Comment: @Huisman I'm not sure what there is to prove about a definition. Both are valid definitions of a phasor in the sense that they will lead to the same relative results, but they are not equivalent (ie. you can't compare phasors of definition 1 with that of definition 2).

Comment: I wouldn't use two different definitions of phasors and telling you can't compare them. Just use \$sin(\omega t) = cos(-\omega t +\pi/2)\$ and you can compare them.

Comment: Well yes, but I meant to not compare them *directly* as I outlined in my answer (the resulting phasors are still linked by a factor \$-j\sqrt{2}\$). But OP's question was if it could be accepted as correct, to which the answer is *yes*, but they are not identical definitions - so not just a different notation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I got confused by my book but it's just a different definition.

Answer (score 1):

It is common practice to give phasor magnitude in RMS.  Good example is your 120V wall outlet.   Peak of that sine wave us around 169V.  It would be nice if they would state that fact somewhere in the text to avoid confusing students unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Note about the terminology:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor): Phasor notation (also known as angle notation) is a mathematical notation used in electronics engineering and electrical engineering. 1∠θ can represent either the vector (cos θ, sin θ) or the complex number cos θ + i sin θ.
- The product of the phasor by the carrier is what turns the phasor with time. This product is often incorrectly named the phasor. This is the case in your textbook.

---

The phasor is a vector written in the form of a complex number, in polar coordinates (norm, angle), and this is a *constant* number:

$$A  \, e^{j \phi}$$

This constant doesn't describe a *sin* nor a *cos* signal. A time element is missing. On the other hand, a carrier provides the time element in the form of an angular distance since t<sub>0</sub>. The carrier is this quantity:

$$e^{j \omega t}$$

The product of both exponentials is a function describing a rotating vector and, when plotted with time as the x axis, it is an helical signal:

$$A \, e^{j \phi} \, e^{j \omega t} = A \, e^{j (\omega t + \phi)}$$

[image]

The carrier multiplies the phasor by some fraction of *j*. In the complex plane, [such operation is a rotation](https://www.themathdoctors.org/complex-numbers-multiplication-and-rotation/).

Now if you project this helix onto the real axis, you get the cosine function. Doing this projection is as simple as taking the real part of the helix:

$$cos(\omega t + \phi) = \Re \; \{ A \, e^{j (\omega t + \phi)} \}$$

Similarly you get the sine function by extracting the imaginary part.

$$sin(\omega t + \phi) = \Im \; \{ A \, e^{j (\omega t + \phi)} \}$$

This is simply an application of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), where we split the complex exponential into its complex parts:

$$cos \phi + j \, sin \phi = A \, e^{j \phi} \equiv \Re \; \{ Ae^{j \phi} \} + \Im \; \{ Ae^{j \phi} \}$$

---

That said, let's look at what is in your book. You now may wonder why we usually simplify:

$$9 \, \cos (2t + 1/2) = 3 \, A \, \cos (2t − 2 + \phi) + 4 \, \cos (2t)$$

into:

$$9 \, e^{j \, 1/2} = 3 \, A \, e^{j (−2 + \phi)} + 4$$

The reason is we are cutting the corner several times. With all the steps the procedure looks like this from the sinusoidal equation:

$$9 \, \cos (2t + 1/2) = 3 \, A \, \cos (2t − 2 + \phi) + 4 \, \cos (2t)$$

First we replace *cos* by the real parts, according to Euler's formula (and what was explained above):

$$9 \, \Re \, \{ \, e^{j2t} \, e^{j \, 1/2} \} = \Re \, \{ 3 \, A e^{j2t} \, e^{j (−2 + \phi)} \} + \Re \, \{ 4 \, e^{j2t}\}$$

The sum of real parts is the real part of the sum:

$$9 \, \Re \, \{ \, e^{j2t} \, e^{j \, 1/2} \} = \Re \, \{ 3 \, A e^{j2t} \, e^{j (−2 + \phi)} + 4 \, e^{j2t} \}$$

Then we get rid of the real part extraction. This is normally a dangerous step, because the only information provided is the real parts are equal. However by releasing the constraint of taking the real parts we are also making the imaginary parts equal. As we don't use them, this unsupported assumption has no consequences.

$$9 \, \, e^{j2t} \, e^{j \, 1/2} = 3 \, A e^{j2t} \, e^{j (−2 + \phi)} + 4 \, e^{j2t}$$

Then we simplify by dividing by the carrier which appears in all terms.

$$9 \, \, e^{j \, 1/2} = 3 \, A e^{j (−2 + \phi)} + 4$$

If you've to deal with *sin*, this is just the same simplification, taking the imaginary part, then getting rid of it with care. Remember the phasor doesn't describe a *cos* nor a *sin*. When multiplied by the carrier, the result describes a *cos* in its real part and a *sin* in its imaginary part. But we can cut corners.